# How to use the Multi Bibliography resource from biblatex with beamer?

Tags: beamer, biblatex, subdividing

I am working with `beamer` and `biblatex`. I am writing a series of lectures and I want each one of them to have a separate bibliographical reference.
I am running

```
pdflatex foo.tex 
biber foo.bcf 
pdflatex foo.tex
```

After that, something strange happens. If I run `pdflatex foo.tex` I get the following error message:

```
Package biblatex Error: Nested 'refsection' environment.
```

If I change the document class from `beamer` to `article`, everything works fine.
The question is: How to fix this error?

EDIT: I added a new MWE to illustrate what I want to do.

The MWE: `foo.tex`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\begin{document}

\section{Chapter One}
\refsection
This is Chapter One.
\cite{goossens93}, \cite{lamport94}, \cite{rahtz89} 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\endrefsection

\newpage
\section{Chapter Two}
\refsection
This is Chapter Two.
\cite{lamport94}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\endrefsection

\newpage
\section{Chapter Three}
\refsection
This is Chapter Three.
\cite{greenwade93}, \cite{patashnik88}, \cite{knuth79}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\endrefsection

\end{document}
```

New MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\begin{document}


\section{Chapter One}
\refsection
\begin{frame}
This is Chapter One.
\cite{goossens93}, \cite{lamport94}, \cite{rahtz89} 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{frame}
\endrefsection

\section{Chapter Two}
\refsection
\begin{frame}
This is Chapter Two.
\cite{lamport94}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{frame}
\endrefsection

\section{Chapter Three}
\refsection
\begin{frame}
This is Chapter Three.
\cite{greenwade93}, \cite{patashnik88}, \cite{knuth79}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{frame}
\endrefsection
\end{document}
```

The bibliography file is: `biblio.bib`

```
@book{goossens93,
    author = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittlebach and Alexander Samarin",
    title = "The Latex Companion A",
    year = "1993",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"

}

@article{greenwade93, 
    author = "George D. Greenwade",
    title = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume = "14",
    number = "3",
    pages = "342--351",
           url=" www.ctan.org"
}

@book{knuth79,
    author = "Donald E. Knuth",
    title = "Tex and Metafont, New Directions in Typesetting",
    year = "1979",
    publisher = "American Mathematical Society and Digital Press",
    address = "Stanford"
}

@book{lamport94,
    author = "Leslie Lamport",
    title = "Latex: A Document Preparation System",
    year = "1994",
    edition = "Second",
    publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
    address = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}

@misc{patashnik88,
    author = "Oren Patashnik",
    title = "{B}ib{T}e{X}ing.  Documentation for General {B}ib{T}e{X} users",
    year = "1988",
    howpublished = "Electronic document accompanying BibTeX
distribution"
}

@techreport{rahtz89,
    author = "Sebastian Rahtz",
    title = "A Survey of {T}ex and graphics",
    year = "1989",
    institution = "Department of Electronics and Computer Science",
    address = "University of Southampton, UK",
    number = "CSTR 89-7"
}
```

Comment: Mhh... the problem seems to lie with the `.nav` file created by `beamer` which contains some lines about `\defcounter {refsection}{0}\relax `. That seems to upset `biblatex` quite a bit. I have as of no no idea how to prevent `beamer` from doing that. (One can manually delete these lines and the compilation will work, but obviously that is not a viable solution.)

Comment: @moewe Your code in the deleted answer works fine for me. You have just to delete the old `.nav` file.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved it by using refsegment instead of refsection. To print the partial bibliography corresponding to a particular refsegment environment you must specifically specify it in the printbibliography command. For example:

```
\printbibliography[segment=2]
```

prints the bibliography from the second refsegment environment. It is not enough to just put \printbibliography in the corresponding refsegment environment (as can be done when using refsection).

See Section 3.11.3 in the manual for biblatex for more detail.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but solved it different. I just removed one biblatex-package option from the LaTeX root file. This is what I had:

```
% Code causing "nested refsection errors"
\documentclass[...]
\usepackage{...}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, refsection=chapter, backend=biber]{biblatex}
   .
   .
\begin{document}
   .
   .
\begin{refsection}
   .
   .
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
   .
   .
\end{document}
```

After removing the refsection=chapter option, results where as expected. So, for me, this worked:

```
% Correct Code 
\documentclass[...]
\usepackage{...}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic, backend=biber]{biblatex}
   .
   .
\begin{document}
   .
   .
\begin{refsection}
   .
   .
\printbibliography
\end{refsection}
   .
   .
\end{document}
```

I can image that the refsection=chapter option auto inserts refsections in the  chapters and became nested refsections with the manually inserted ones.

Comment: That is indeed the case. With `refsection=chapter` every `\chapter` starts a new `refsection` automatically. The OP did not have this problem since their code does not contain `refsection=chapter`.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the proper `beamer` way of getting a new frame, which is not `\newpage` but wrapping the contents of one frame into one `\begin{frame}...\end{frame}` environment, everything works rather fine.

In response to your update: If you use `\section` outside of a frame, this causes trouble with your `\refsections`. You need to place the `\section` command in a frame.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\section{Chapter One}
\begin{refsection}
This is Chapter One.
\cite{companion}, \cite{coleridge}, \cite{cicero} 
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{Chapter Two}
\begin{refsection}
This is Chapter Two.
\cite{coleridge}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\section{Chapter Three}
\begin{refsection}
This is Chapter Three.
\cite{pines}, \cite{moraux}, \cite{knuth:ct:a}
\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @moeve Take a look ate the new MWE. The problem persists.